# curl fails with 403 error but wget succeeds

Tags: ubuntu, curl, http-status-code-403

I have a large 3rd party provided script that installs and builds an app. It has just started failing on the line:

```
curl -f http://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inode64.c
```

it returns a 403 'forbidden' error

however doing wget on the same file succeeds

```
wget http://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inode64.c
```

I am using ubuntu 22.04 curl version 7.81 (though I also tried 8.1.2) - and I have observed the same behaviour from 2 different computers

Does anyone else see the same behaviour? I'm reluctant to change the script as it isn't mine and it used to work. Is there anything else I can try?

Some suggestions online seem to imply using different credentials. How do I supply these to curl - ideally without changing the script

I have used the -v option in curl and the -d option in wget to get diagnostic information (posted below) but I'm not enlightened

```
**curl -f -v https://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inode64.c**
*   Trying 93.93.131.127:443...
* Connected to www.mjr19.org.uk (93.93.131.127) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.mjr19.org.uk
*  start date: Aug 12 09:35:52 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 10 09:35:51 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.mjr19.org.uk" matched cert's "www.mjr19.org.uk"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET /sw/inode64.c HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.mjr19.org.uk
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 09:32:36 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< Content-Length: 282
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
* The requested URL returned error: 403
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
`

**wget -d  https://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inode64.c**
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.21.2 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/md1/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'inode64.c' (UTF-8) -> 'inode64.c' (UTF-8)
--2023-09-29 10:33:32--  https://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inode64.c
Resolving www.mjr19.org.uk (www.mjr19.org.uk)... 93.93.131.127, 2a00:1098:0:86:1000::10
Caching www.mjr19.org.uk => 93.93.131.127 2a00:1098:0:86:1000::10
Connecting to www.mjr19.org.uk (www.mjr19.org.uk)|93.93.131.127|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000055a3132759c0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x000055a313277110
certificate:
  subject: CN=www.mjr19.org.uk
  issuer:  CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host www.mjr19.org.uk

---request begin---
GET /sw/inode64.c HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mjr19.org.uk
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 09:33:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Vary: User-Agent
Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Dec 2019 12:17:59 GMT
ETag: "1d03-598cbafd9f0a9"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7427
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/x-csrc

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Length: 7427 (7.3K) [text/x-csrc]
Saving to: ‘inode64.c’

inode64.c                            100%[=====================================================================>]   7.25K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-09-29 10:33:32 (119 MB/s) - ‘inode64.c’ saved [7427/7427]
```

Comment: _"Some suggestions online seem to imply using different credentials."_ - what "credentials", the resource you are trying to request there appears to be publicly available without supplying _any_ sort of credentials.

Comment: `The requested URL returned error: 403` - most likely that will be the case, because the remote party did not like _some_ detail of your request, probably the request headers. Try sending a different `User-Agent` with your cURL request first of all, and see if that changes anything. (Try the value the wget request uses, and/or one that matches that of a current browser.)

Comment: You are right - adding -A Wget/1.21.2 to the curl options fixes the problem. I was hoping to find a solution that I could apply without modifying the script. I guess that confirms that it is a change on the server website rather than on my machine though

Comment: Yes, that would be a change on the remote end in all likelihood. They might have gotten too many (abusive) cURL requests, so that they started to block that particular UA.